# How many Java STRUCT Objects (oracle objects) can be sent to Stored procedure at a time. Any Limitation?

Tags: java, oracle

Wanted to know about any limitations to send no of Oracle Objects to Stored procedure at a time.

Comment: Is this the number of parameters a procedure can have or is it the number of elements that can be placed into a collection or do you want to know both and then multiply the two together?

Answer (score 3):

From Oracle Documentation [PL/SQL Program Limits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/limits.htm):

> **Item**: number of formal parameters in an explicit cursor, function, or procedure
> **Limit**: 65536

From [Referencing Collection Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#CJABEBEA)

> The allowed subscript ranges are:
>
> - For nested tables, 1..2147483647 (the upper limit of **`PLS_INTEGER`**).
> - For varrays, 1.. ***`size_limit`***, where you specify the limit in the declaration (***`size_limit`*** cannot exceed 2147483647).

So if you have the maximum number of parameters in a procedure (65536) and each is a collection (which can contain 2147483647 elements) then you could pass `65536 * 2147483647 = 140737488289792` collection elements (which could be objects).

This, of course, does not consider that you could create objects which contain other objects...

... or that the system might run out of memory before you reach this limit.

... or that the driver you are using might have lower limits.